# ES6 export template generator

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Using CommonJS, I can do something like the following:

`generator.js`:

```
module.exports = (...args) => ({
  create: makeCreate(...args),
  remove: makeRemove(...args),
});
```

`model.js`:

```
const generate = require('generator.js');

module.exports = generate('my-model');
```

`use.js`:

```
const { create, remove } = require('model.js');

module.exports = {
  doCreate: () => create('something'),
  doRemove: () => remove('something else'),
};
```

Using ES6 modules, I can refactor to the following:

`generator.mjs`:

```
export default (...args) => ({
  create: makeCreate(...args),
  remove: makeRemove(...args),
});
```

`model.mjs`:

```
import generate from 'generator.mjs';

export default generate('my-model');
```

`use.mjs`:

```
import model from 'model.mjs';

export const doCreate = () => model.create('something');
export const doRemove = () => model.remove('something else');
```

However, the way `model.mjs` exports itself means that I *cannot* do this:

`use.mjs`:

```
import { create, remove } from 'model.mjs';

export const doCreate = () => create('something');
export const doRemove = () => remove('something else');
```

I can't think of a way to concisely define the exports in `generator.mjs` and `model.mjs` to make the above possible. Can you?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

You can do something like this in `use.mjs`

```
import model from 'model.mjs';

const {create, remove} = model;

export const doCreate = () => create('something');
export const doRemove = () => remove('something else');
```

Another solution is:

In `model.mjs`

```
import generate from "./generator.js";

export const { create, remove } = generate("my-model");
```

And in `use.mjs`

```
import { create, remove } from "./model.js";

export const doCreate = () => create("something");
export const doRemove = () => remove("something else");
```

Comment: The first solution is essentially what I'm doing now. I like the second solution. Are there actually multiple exports? Would it work without babel?

Comment: Here you have a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/8l3rl1716j yes it should work with/without babel. multiple exports?

Comment: My question was whether each of `create` and `remove` would be parsed as exports properly without executing `generate` first.

Comment: If you no execute generate you cannot export its result